# Remove all markers, polygons, and event listeners from a Google Map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a Google Map created with Google Maps API 3 that has several markers, polygons, and event listeners.  When I push a button, I want remove all those objects from the map, and then have it reload again with nothing.  Is there a central function that can just reset or redraw a map?  Seems like it should be easy but I can't get it to work.

Comment: What does your code look like?  Can you provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates what you are trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to turn on and off the items you should first collect them in arrays of objects and then recursively should be assigned to each of these items the value null for map with the overlay's setMap()  method in this case `yourObj.setMap(null);`.
To turn them on just reassign the objects the object map usually `obj.setMap(map);`  Note that this does not remove the objects. This is limited only to remove them from the map. to permanently delete items you need to add the assignment `yourObj = null;`